# How is for loop parsed internally as in assembly language?

Tags: c, for-loop

How does a for loop work internally in terms of the machine language when the expressions are not written. For example

```
int i=0 , j=1;
for(;;)
```

Comment: Its an infinite loop.

Comment: @Osiris is there any other way of coming out of the loop other than break?

Comment: With a `goto`for example, but thats really not good practice.

Comment: why are you trying to break out of an infinite loop without break?

Comment: Or return from that function.

Comment: Thanks. Understood @kiranBiradar

Comment: What about when the expressions are shuffled like for(i<2; i++; ). The loop still gets executed. Isn't there any kind of protocol?

Comment: @HarishRajora: in that specific example, `i<2` will be evaluated once before the loop begins, then `i++` will be evaluated before each iteration - as long as the result is non-zero, the loop will execute.  The position of each expression matters; you can't just shift everything left one position.

Comment: It will work exactly like while(true); infinite

Answer (score 5):

A `for` loop with a missing middle expression is an infinite loop.

From section 6.8.5.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *1* The statement
>
> ```
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling
>   expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
>   The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after
>   each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the
>   scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the
>   declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions;
>   it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of
>   the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
>   evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the
>   controlling expression.
>
> *2* Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. **An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.**

Because a missing "expression-2" is replaced with a non-zero constant, and because a non-zero value evaluates to true, this gives you an infinite loop.

Comment: I see there can be shuffling of the expressions also like for (i<2; ;i++) and still the loop runs.

Comment: @HarishRajora It is still an infinite loop then, which increments `i` every turn.

Comment: and if for(;i++;) is written then? Just last ques.

Comment: @HarishRajora In that case `i<2` is only executed at the start of the loop and its value is discarded, and as before the missing "expression-2" gives you an infinite loop.

Comment: @HarishRajora That will increment `i` until it evaluates to false which is (if starting value is positive) probably a signed int overflow and undefined behavior.

Comment: @Osiris Thanks a lot. Understood.

Answer (score 3):

All the parts of the for-loop are optional:

- initialization: you can do the initialization outside of the loop.
- condition: will be true if empty
- last part: you can also do nothing.

`for(;;)` is an infinite loop (if there are no `break`s inside the loop).

Answer (score 2):

The expressions which are not present do nothing.

If the initialisation is absent, nothing is initialised.

If the test is absent, nothing is tested (and the body loops forever unless it contains a`break`, `return`, etc.)

If the increment is absent, nothing is incremented.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop contains three clauses. They can be virtually any expression, but the standard way of using it is `for(<init>; <loop condition>; <loop variable increment>)`. All of these are optional: if you omit the loop condition, it will be replaced by a constant that evaluates to true. You could for instance replace

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
   ...
}
```

with

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ) {
    ...
    i++;
}
```

`for(;;)` is an infinite loop. Any `for` loop that has second statement omitted is an infinite loop.

There are basically three ways to get out of an infinite loop, `break`, `return` and `goto`.

In most cases you should use `break` or `return`, but `goto` also has its usage.

- If you want to just break out of the loop and continue after it, use `break`.
- If you want to quit the function that contains the loop, use `return`. However, this can be bad practice since it will likely violate the "single exit" practice.
- If you want to break out of a *nested* loop, goto may be appropriate.

And yes, you could exit a loop by calling `exit()` or simply make the program crash too, but I think you get the point.

**Question from comments**

> for(i<2; i++; )

This does not make much sense. The first expression `i<2` will not affect anything and is likely to be optimized away by the compiler. The second expression `i++` will evaluate to false if `i` is `0`:

- if `i` has an initial value of `0`, the loop body is not evaluated at all.
- if `i` is initially a negative number. The loop iterates until `i` reaches the value `0`, the last iteration occurs with `i == 0` and the next test will end the loop.
- if `i` has an `unsigned` type and is greater than `0`. The loop iterates until `i` reaches the maximum value for its type and wraps to `0`, the last iteration occurs with `i == 0` and the next test stops the loop. If `i` is not unsigned, arithmetic overflow will cause *undefined behavior*, which is bad: the loop may stop or continue indefinitely, depending on the compiler choices, or anything else may occur.

Comment: @user3386109 Was adding it when you wrote the comment, but thanks.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix some typos and refine the explanation for the `i++` condition expression.